# the multiplication of a code between two numbers incorrectly outputting number

Tags: javascript

```
function showMultiples(num, numMultiples){
    for(i=1; i<=numMultiples; i++){
        var multiple = num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i;

    }

    return multiple;
} 
console.log('showMultiples(2,8) returns: ' + showMultiples(2,8));
```

For this code, what the function should do is, by looking at num and numMultiples variable, it should give you the list of multiplication that is possible with the two numbers. Therefore the console should print out 
2x1=2 2x2=4 2x3=6 2x4=8 2x5=10 2x6=12 2x7=14 2x8=16

However, this code prints out 2x8 = 16 any guess to why?

Comment: the console prints out 2 x 8 = 16 when it should print out
2x1 = 2
2x2= 4 
2x3= 6
 and so on until it  reaches the numMultiples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the value to `multiple` then returning it in the end, when your loop has finished, meaning multiple will be `2x8`. If you do a `console.log(multiple)` right under `var multiple = num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i;` you will see it print out correctly.

EDIT:

```
function showMultiples(num, numMultiples){
var result = [];
for(i=1; i<=numMultiples; i++){
    result.push(num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i);
}

return result.join(' ');
}
```

Add results to an `array` and when the `function` completes, `join` the values inside the `array` and return the results.

Comment: oh im not allowed to use any console.log statements inside the function. I am only able to return

Comment: thank you for big help! Thanks for your .push and .join logic, I fixed an error I had from other assignments as well!

Answer (score 0):

You only have one print statement, and that is outside of the loop. If you want to print multiple times, you need to put the print statement inside of the loop, something like this:

```
function showMultiples(num, numMultiples) {
    console.log(`showMultiples(${num}, ${numMultiples}) returns:`);
    Array.from({length: numMultiples}, (v, k) => k + 1).
        forEach(i => console.log(`${num}×${i} = ${num * i}`));
}
showMultiples(2, 8)
// showMultiples(2, 8) returns:
// 2×1 = 2
// 2×2 = 4
// 2×3 = 6
// 2×4 = 8
// 2×5 = 10
// 2×6 = 12
// 2×7 = 14
// 2×8 = 16
```

However, that is bad design. You shouldn't mix data transformation and I/O. It is much better to separate the two and build the data up first completely, *then* print it:

```
function showMultiples(num, numMultiples) {
    return Array.from({length: numMultiples}, (v, k) => k + 1).
        map(i => `${num}×${i} = ${num * i}`).
        join(", ");
} 
console.log(`showMultiples(2, 8) returns: ${showMultiples(2, 8)}`);
// showMultiples(2, 8) returns: 2×1 = 2, 2×2 = 4, 2×3 = 6, 2×4 = 8, 2×5 = 10, 2×6 = 12, 2×7 = 14, 2×8 = 16
```

This is much more idiomatic ECMAScript.